# "These dependencies were not found" error in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I just added a new library ([@vueform/multiselect](https://github.com/vueform/multiselect)). After that I got so many errors. First, I got incompatible engine "node" error, I solved it to write this: yarn add <package_name> --ignore-engines
Now, I'm getting "These dependencies were not found" error. How can I fix it?

```
These dependencies were not found:

* core-js/modules/es.array.concat in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.array.every in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.array.fill in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.array.filter in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.array.for-each in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.array.from in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.array.includes in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.array.index-of in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.array.iterator in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.array.join in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.array.map in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.array.reduce in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.array.reverse in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.array.slice in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.array.some in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.function.name in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.map in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.number.constructor in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.object.get-own-property-descriptor in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.object.get-own-property-descriptors in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.object.keys in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.object.to-string in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.promise in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.reflect.apply in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.reflect.construct in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.reflect.delete-property in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.reflect.get-prototype-of in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.regexp.exec in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.regexp.to-string in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.string.includes in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.string.iterator in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.string.match in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.string.replace in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.string.split in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.string.starts-with in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.string.trim in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.symbol in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.symbol.description in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/es.symbol.iterator in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/web.dom-collections.for-each in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
* core-js/modules/web.dom-collections.iterator in ./node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/.internal/canvg/index.js
```

By the way, I tried to install all but I got same error again. it did not fix it.

Comment: `yarn add <package_name> --ignore-engines`, this is probably not a good idea. By-passing an issue will not make the rest work. Fix the initial one. Which version of Node are you using? NPM or yarn maybe? For which version do you want it to work?

Comment: yes, it wasn't a good idea. I use yarn

Comment: And the rest...?

Comment: I'm using yarn version: 1.22.19

Comment: And the rest...?

Comment: Thank you. I solve it with command "npm install node-sass".

Answer (score 0):

OP fixed the issue with `npm install node-sass`.